# momentjs week difference float value

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datediff, date-difference

Im using momentjs in a nodeapp and then trying to find the difference between 2 dates in weeks like below,

```
var serviceCreated = moment(new Date(service.createdAt)), //fetching this value from DB
    currentDate    = moment(new Date()),
    delta          = currentDate.diff(serviceCreated, 'weeks') //it returns the value as integer
```

As mentioned in the DOC if i have stated `currentDate.diff(serviceCreated, 'weeks', true)` then it provides a float value say for example if the difference is 4 weeks and 4 days i would expect this value to be some where around 4.4XXXX so i can grab the value after the decimal place and then have it as 4 days. But this logic is not working all the times there is a mismatch here and there.

So bottom line is via momentjs can i get the difference in weeks and days at the same time, if that's possible then i can add those days which might range from 1 to 6 to the delta value.

I also did try something with http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/preciserange/ but that gives me the total days and the other one gives me the total weeks, i'm trying to get the difference in weeks and days at the same time.

**Example:**

```
var serviceCreated = moment(new Date('08/02/2016')),
    currentDate    = moment(new Date('10/16/2016'));
    currentDate.diff(serviceCreated, 'weeks', true) // returns 10.633490008267195
```

which i assume is 10 weeks and 6 days but in actual the difference between the above dates is 10 weeks and 5 days (without including the end date)

Comment: "But this logic is not working all the times there is a mismatch here and there" how so? Do you have an example of it not working?

Comment: Just added an example in the original query.

Comment: You are incorrect in your assumption that `10.63` of a week is 10 weeks and 6 days. It's 10 weeks and 0.63 of a week, which is `(7 * 0.63)` == ~4.4 days...